# If V is finite dimensional and W is infinite dimensional then V and W are not isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let on contrary that V and W are isomorphic then there is one-one correspondence between its basis elements .
Let $\lbrace v_1,v_2,....v_n\rbrace$ be a basis for V and $ \lbrace w_1,w_2,......\rbrace $be a basis for W then suppose f is an isomorphism between V and W say
f(v_1)=w_1
f(v_2)=w_2....... 
f(v_n)=w_n....
There is no preimage of $w_{n+1}$ which implies f is not onto which is contradiction.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Am i correct, I showed that f is not onto and hence they are not isomorphic, is this correct method?

Comment: You should put the question into the body.

Answer (score 1):

You are right but a more correct redaction would be:
"Assume $f : V \to W$ is an isomorphism. Pick a basis $v_1,\dots , v_n$ of $V$. Then $f(v_1),\dots , f(v_n)$ is a basis of $W$ which is impossible as $W$ is infinite dimensional. QED"

**Remark** : Here we use that the image of a basis by an isomorphism is also a basis (of the codomain).